# Why is my nested resource form trying to use a non-existent path method when I've already set the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, erb, nested-resources

I have the following routes defined in my application:

```
resources :users do
  resources :data_sets
end
```

The form `data_sets/new` is accessed from the following link:

```
<%= link_to "New Data Set", new_user_data_set_path(user) %>
```

The form is defined as such:

```
<%= form_with model: @data_set, url: [@data_set.author, @data_set] do |form| %>
  <!-- form contents... -->
<% end %>
```

The form gives the following error upon loading:

```
Showing .../app/views/data_sets/new.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `data_sets_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007ffd2d1dcf90>:0x00007ffd292a63d0>
```

The following parameters were passed:

```
{ "user_id" => "1" }
```

Similar questions posted here seem to indicate that defining the URL typically solves problems with nested resource forms, but as you can see I already have. What else is going on here?

Comment: are you sure that data_set.author has a value? maybe that's the reason why it's looking for path of just @data_set and not the nested one. because the syntax seems correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[`form_with`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)** helper build the nested url from the array you passed. But in case of new record, `@data_set.author` returns nil and the form tries to reach `data_sets_path` which does not exist.

If your form is just for the "new" action you can write:

```
<%= form_with model: @data_set, url: [:user, @data_set] do |form| %>
```

If you share the form between "new" and "edit", you can write a condition like that:

```
<%= form_with model: @data_set, url: [(@data_set.new_record? ? :user : @data_set.author), @data_set] do |form| %>
```